# How to remove PHP extension, receiving no data, Ubuntu-server

Tags: ubuntu, php

I've setup my lamp server with ubuntu-server. I installed XDebug and now I get

> "Zero Sized Reply"

or

> "Your request returned no data. Please check your url and try again"

How do I remove XDebug from the command line? There's nothing in php.ini

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of PHP extension installs on Linux use their own .ini files for configuration. Take a look in /etc/php.d/ for any files called xdebug.ini. Comment out any lines in the file using a semi-colon and re-start Apache.

That should disable it.